# PHP: Getting the include/require process right

Tags: php, optimization

I am looking for a better method for handling relative paths in PHP.  An issue I ran into was including a file from a sub-directory that was also including files.  Using this process resulted in relative paths breaking.  To alleviate this issue was by changing the variable (path) if the file didn't exist.  But, for some reason, it doesn't settle well with me as I think there has to be a better way to handle this.

**Example:**

`ROOT/config/config.php`

`ROOT/includes/functions.php`

`ROOT/includes/header.php` <-- includes `functions.php` and `config.php`

`ROOT/index.php` <-- includes `header.php`

`ROOT/admin/index.php` <--- also includes `header.php` (as `../includes/header.php`) and has the code below to fix the broken links

Below is the code I used which did solve the problem but I am just verifying that this is okay or if there is a better method to handling relative file paths.

```
    define('PREV_DIR', '../');

    $config_file = './config/config.php';
    $functions_file = './includes/functions.php';

    if ( !file_exists($config_file)) {
        $config_file = PREV_DIR . './config/config.php';
    }

    if ( !file_exists($functions_file)) {
        $functions_file = PREV_DIR . './config/config.php';
    }    

    include $config_file;
    include $functions_file;
```

While I have achieved my goal, I just want to move forward with best practices and minimize a sloppy approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your project is simple enough (from what I can see in your post), you could define path constants in your configuration file, thus making it simpler to rename / replace them just by changing the directory name and the value of the constant.

For example:

```
<?php #index.php

define('ROOT', __dir__);
define('CONFIG_DIR', ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config');
define('INCLUDES_DIR', ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'includes');
```

For classes, there is a standard that most use and that is highly recommended, and that is the [PSR-4 Autoload standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), where you have Namespace/SubNamespaces/ClassName.